# Configuring apache solr search on localhost gives error: HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: ubuntu, solr

When I try to access localhost:8983/solr it displays the following error.

> HTTP ERROR 500

```
Problem accessing /solr/admin. Reason:

{msg=SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Could not load config file /home/ahmad/solr-4.6.0/example/solr/collection1/solrconfig.xml,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Could not load config file /home/ahmad/solr-4.6.0/example/solr/collection1/solrconfig.xml
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:818)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:297)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:197)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load config file /home/ahmad/solr-4.6.0/example/solr/collection1/solrconfig.xml
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:525)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:592)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:271)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:263)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
... 1 more

Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: solrconfig.xml contains more than one value for config path: indexConfig/useCompoundFile
at org.apache.solr.core.Config.getNode(Config.java:251)
at org.apache.solr.core.Config.getNode(Config.java:228)
at org.apache.solr.core.Config.getVal(Config.java:362)
at org.apache.solr.core.Config.getBool(Config.java:406)
at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexConfig.<init>(SolrIndexConfig.java:139)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:157)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:522)
... 9 more
,code=500}

Powered by Jetty://
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SolrException: solrconfig.xml contains more than one value for config path: indexConfig/useCompoundFile`

This error says that you have multiple occurrences of `indexConfig > useCompoundFile` values in your `solrconfig.xml` (that is multiple occurences of `compoundFile` under `indexConfig`)

Just remove these values as to make them appear only once in the whole file

It's a [change that appears in SOLR-4.5.0](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/CHANGES.txt)

Comment: I have read the file but I found only two occurrences of indexConfig. One is `<indexConfig>` and other is `</indexConfig>`. There is no other occurrence of indexConfig.

Comment: and `useCompoundFile` ?

Comment: In this indexConfig tag there are two occurrences of `<useCompoundFile>false</useCompoundFile>`

Comment: so, remove one, and you'll be fine :-) I've made a slight mistake on my interpretation of the error message. I update accordingly.

Comment: There were two other multiple occurrences i-e `<ramBufferSizeMB>32</ramBufferSizeMB>` and `<mergeFactor>10</mergeFactor>`. I removed these also and it is working now :-)